# Alglib library(C++)

Tags: c++, fft, alglib

I need help concerning libraries Alglib namely FFT. As I understand it, the input is a string, and the output is the same.

```
complex_1d_array z = "[1i,1i,1i,1i]"; - input
```

Can I make the input as an array? Thanks in advance.